# Searching/replacing exact word in vim by default

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

In vim when searching or replacing an exact word you need to type:

```
\<word\>
```

to match it exactly, this is cumbersome to type, and I find myself wanting to search/replace exact words a lot more often by default than part of a word. Is there a way to let vim use exact words by default, and then turn this option off/on when necessary?

Comment: I'm not sure why you thing Vim doesn't match the exact word but I suspect that you mean it doesn't respect the case of your pattern. If that's what you're talking about have a look at [`:h 'ignorecase'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27ignorecase%27) and [`:h 'smartcase'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27smartcase%27) which change the behavior of the searches and the handling of case in patterns.

Comment: what I mean is if I search for head it will match header too, this is not what I want most of the time, and to just match head I need \<head\>

Comment: Oh ok I see. I'm not sure there is a built-in way to change that, let's hope someone can help you.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't an option to treat the whole pattern as word bounded as far as I know.  Since you want to *replace*, that means the text is already in the buffer.  You could use `*` or `#` on the word in normal mode which performs the `\<word\>` search for you.  Then, `cgn` to replace the next occurrence, and `.` to repeat it.

Alternatively, once a search has been made with `*`, you could use it to start a substitution pattern: `:%s//something/g`.

This can be made into a key map: `nnoremap <leader>r *:%s//`.  It's used the same way as `*` except it will also begin a substitution in the command line that you can finish yourself.

Comment: Also note, that `*` on a word does `\<word\>` while `g*` does `word` searches. Same workflow applies using `<c-r>` but now you can chose which type of search and replace you perform.

Comment: You don't need `<C-R>/`. Just `:%s//replacement/g` with an empty search pattern will use the current search pattern, the one you created with `*`. See `:help last-pattern`.

Comment: @garyjohn Didn't know that!  My life just got a little bit easier.  I'll update the answer for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do

```
:nnoremap / /\<\><left><left>
```

To make the search key `/` naturally expand into `/\<\>` and place the cursor within the search pattern.